# Immutable value of type [Card] only has mutating values of name append

Tags: swift

I have a Card class and a Player class.

In my Player class I have a function that takes a [Card] array and adds a Card to it.

However, when I call...

```
myCardArray.append(myCard)
```

...I get the error

```
Immutable value of type [Card] only has mutating values of name append
```

I can't figure out why this is? Why would this be immutable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

without more code, we can only guess what happened

sounds like you are doing something like

```
func addCard(_ myCardArray: [Card]) -> [Card] {
    let myCard = Card()
    myCardArray.append(myCard)
    return myCardArray
}
```

the problem is that `myCardArray` is immutable, as error message said, you can't modify it

you can declare `myCardArray` mutable use `var`

```
func addCard(var _ myCardArray: [Card]) -> [Card] {
    let myCard = Card()
    myCardArray.append(myCard)
    return myCardArray
}
```

or create a mutable copy of it

```
func addCard(_ myCardArray: [Card]) -> [Card] {
    let myCard = Card()
    var mutableMyCardArray = myCardArray
    mutableMyCardArray.append(myCard)
    return mutableMyCardArray 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bryan! Adding the var keyword worked. I wonder why this is, I don't remember ever having to use this on a parameter.

Comment: @user3356655 by default, parameters are immutable like declared with `let`. it is mentioned somewhere in the doc but I am too lazy to find it out now.

Comment: "or create a mutable copy of it" There is no point in taking a constant parameter just to assign it to another variable.

Answer (score 0):

Values in a dictionary can be updated using this method only if the dictionary is defined with the var keyword (that is, if the dictionary is mutable)
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Dictionary.html

Comment: This is an array, not dictionary.